# pandas, apply function and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following pandas code, why is `df` not need in the arguments?

```
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b]), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity')
```

Comment: The function passed to `.apply` get's passed either a column or a row, as a `Series` depending on whether you used `axis=0` or `axis=1`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter is passed implicitly to a function in the apply call. Therefore, it does not appear in the args again. You could actually rewrite the anonymous function in the apply to

```
 df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: sum(x["Weight (oz.)"] * x["Quantity"]))
```

without using args here at all. It get's clear, that `x` is the first parameter which is passed without explicitly passing it.

Answer (score 0):

more generally, `apply` is an method of the DataFrame instance `df`.

This boils down to meaning that apply is passed a self parameter implicitly. Imagine the call to be be `apply(self, *args)`.

Here `self` refers to the DataFrame instance `df`; so now it should be clear that passing `df` again would be redundant (if it were allowed).

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat related and worth mentioning that you don't need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) at all here, and can speed up the operation considerably by only grouping the product of your two columns of interest by 
your `'Category'` column, e.g.

```
(df['Weight (oz.)'] * df['Quantity']).groupby(df.Category).sum()
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(category=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]*(10**6), 
                       a = np.random.randint(1, 10, 9*(10**6)), 
                       b=np.random.randint(1, 10, 9*(10**6))))

%timeit (df.a*df.b).groupby(df.category).sum()
1 loop, best of 3: 560 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: sum(x.a*x.b))
1 loop, best of 3: 3.34 s per loop
```